# Numpy slicing x,y,z array for variable z

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 3d array of position data, which I'd like to take `2-d` slices from. However the slices vary in the `z` depth with `x` (and `y` eventually).

E.g.
An array `100x100x100`, and I want the first slice to be the parallelogram starting at

`x=0,y=0 => x=100,y=100` containing the points in the `z` direction `0-25` when at `x=0`, and changing linearly to `z=25-50` by the time `x=100`. So a sort of diagonal slice.

Is there an efficient way to do this in numpy. Ideally something like

```
    newarray = oldarray[z> x/100*25.0 && z < 25+x/100*25.0]
```

Comment: Could you give an example (I don't quite follow), like what you expect this to look like as a 3x3?

Comment: If you think of the data as a cube, then a simple slice would be to take a flat section off the top. OK - in 2-d it would be 
[[6, 5, 4],
 [1, 2, 3],
 [5, 7, 9]] 
a 1 deep slice would be [ 6, 5, 4]. However I want a semi diagonal slice, which might be [6, 5, 3] (the 3 coming from the 2nd row).
Followed by [1, 2, 9]. Now scale it up to 100x100, and take a slanting cut starting on first row, to include the subsequent 25 rows, on the LHS, but on the RHS of the array taking rows 25-50 and interpolating between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your desired data will probably not be representable as a strided view of the original, you will have to use *advanced indexing* to pull out the coordinates you want.

```
c = np.r_[:100]
xi = c.reshape((100, 1, 1))
yi = c.reshape((1, 100, 1))
zi = np.empty((100, 100, 25), dtype=int)
for x in xrange(100):
    for y in xrange(100):
        zi[x,y] = np.arange(x*25/100, x*25/100+25) # or whatever other function

newarray = oldarray[xi, yi, zi]
```

Slicing `oldarray` using the numpy arrays `xi`, `yi`, `zi` triggers advanced indexing. Numpy will create a new array having the same shape as that formed by broadcasting `xi`, `yi`, `zi` (so in this case, since `xi` is (100, 1, 1), `yi` is (1, 100, 1), and `zi` is (100, 100, 25), the output will be (100, 100, 25)).

Numpy then fills that array using corresponding elements of `xi`, `yi` and `zi` (with broadcasting), so that `newarray[i, j, k] = oldarray[xi[i, 0, 0], yi[0, j, 0], zi[i, j, k]]`

Comment: I've read this through a few times, and can't see how it works conceptually!

Comment: Yeah, *advanced indexing* can be a bit of a headbreaker. It's quite different from standard indexing. I'll add an explanation...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [`map_coordinates`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.map_coordinates.html). Here is a small example for a 3x3x3 volume:

```
a = np.arange(27).reshape(3,3,3)
xi,yi = np.meshgrid(range(3),range(3))
zi = xi*.25+yi*.25
inds = np.array([xi.reshape(1,9),yi.reshape(1,9),zi.reshape(1,9)])
ndimage.map_coordinates(a,inds).reshape(3,3)
>> array([[ 0,  9, 18],
       [ 3, 12, 22],
       [ 6, 16, 25]])
```

Note there may be a better way to do this without all the reshaping.